How To Allow Popup Ads Only On Certain Website Pages Using .htaccess File
As a webmaster I would like to exclude popup ads on certain specific webpages on my website whos url ends with a particular string. Example :
https://mywebsite/some-slug-variable/?gallery=submit
I am using a popads code that is in a popads.php file in the root directory of the site.
I would like the popups to be displayed on the entire website as normal with the exclusion of urls ending in the string ?gallery=submit
How would one go about accomplishing this?
I would assume one would have to write a rule in the .htaccess file...

Maybe you can redirect to a 404 those urls

Share the contents of your popads.php

If your popads.php simply gets included into all of your pages(?), then you should probably just do it in there. Wrap what it does into something like if (empty($_GET['gallery']) || 'submit' !== $_GET['gallery']) { ... }

@CBroe Yes, it's a simp  call in the header template. I will try your code to see if it works. Thanks!

@CBroe what do I put in the curly brackets?

The part that outputs those ads. Could probably be more or less the whole file content, I suppose.

@CBroe I tried this line of code in between the  tags & it worked! 
